# Как преобразовать UCS-2 HEX в UTF16 BE java

Tags: java, decode

у меня имеется строка в которой зашифрован текст смс зашифрованный в формате USC2 полученный с GSM модема

Я пытаюсь его перекодировать в UTF16 но ничего не выходит. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class USC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg = "0412044B0020043F043E043B044C043704430435044204350441044C002004420430044004380444043D044B043C0020043F043B0430043D043E043C0020002204110438002B002200200441002000300033002E00310032002E0032003000320031002E002004230442043E0447043D04380442044C002004430441043B043E04320438044F";

        byte[] b = msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Компилятор

```
[B@4b67cf4d

Process finished with exit code 0
```

На онлайн декодере через сервис https://dencode.com/
выдает следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы в консоль выводите результат вызова toString метода у класса массива. Вам надо массив байтов в строку переделать. Примерно так: `String result = new String(b);` и уже `result` выводить в логи

Comment: Попробовал так) вернул ту же строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На котлине это можно [так сделать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66614516/3212712):

```
fun String.decodeHex(): ByteArray {
    check(length % 2 == 0) { "Must have an even length" }

    return chunked(2)
        .map { it.toInt(16).toByte() }
        .toByteArray()
}

fun main() {
   val test = "0412044B0020043F043E043B044C043704430435044204350441044C002004420430044004380444043D044B043C0020043F043B0430043D043E043C0020002204110438002B002200200441002000300033002E00310032002E0032003000320031002E002004230442043E0447043D04380442044C002004430441043B043E04320438044F"
    
    val bytes = test.decodeHex()
    val bytesDecoded = String(bytes, Charsets.UTF_16BE)
    println("bytesDecoded: $bytesDecoded")
    //выведет
    //bytesDecoded: Вы пользуетесь тарифным планом "Би+" с 03.12.2021. Уточнить условия
}
```

Проверить можно тут: https://play.kotlinlang.org/

---

На Java переводить лень, алгоритм такой:

1. Преобразуем строку в список строк, деля изначальную строку на части по 2 символа
2. Полученный список строк преобразуем список Byte, применяя `Integer.parseInt(stringToConvert, 2)`, после чего полученное `Integer` преобзазуем в `Byte`
3. Полученный список Byte приобразуем в массив Byte
4. Конвертим массив Byte в строку в кодировке `UTF_16BE`

Comment: Буду признателен если переведете) у меня на выходе в Java получилась опять какая то хрень K  ?>;L7C5B5AL  B0@8D=K<  ?;0=><   "8 + "  A   0 3 . 1 2 . 2 0 2 1 .  #B>G=8BL  CA;>28O

Comment: @Zenk0, покажите какой код у вас получился (в правке к вопросу) - попробую помочь)

Comment: победил)  BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
        byte[] a = bi.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(new String(a, Charset.forName("UTF-16")));